# is there a way to calculating classification time in matlab?

Tags: matlab, time, classification

I want to learn classification time for different classifiers with the same train and test data sets. Is there a way to calculating classification time in matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use `cputime`, which fit your needs. Indeed, in a code like:

```
t = cputime;
% run a classifier here
dt = cputime - t;
```

`dt` gives you the amount of cpu time spent on the classifier code, rather than the elapsed time in the real world.

However, according to your needs, you can choose also between `tic/toc` and `clock/etime` by placing them respectively before each classifier is run, and after each classifier execution.

Also, have a look to `profile viewer`, which is an excellent code profiling tool.